# Changing connection string in app.config for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I am using Entity Framework. In app.config there is stored connection string that EF generates for my database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="votemeEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/VoteModel.csdl|res://*/VoteModel.ssdl|res://*/VoteModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;User Id=root;database=voteme&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="VoteMe.Properties.Settings.votemeConnectionString"
      connectionString="server=localhost;User Id=root;database=voteme"
      providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I need to set Charset in this connection string. How do I do it so my EF use this connection string without any problems?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the property at the end of the EF connection string, just before the `&quot;`.

```
...abase=voteme;charset=UTF8;&quot;"
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Just make sure that the value is properly XML escaped (if needed), otherwise you will break the config file.

Comment: and that is the question =) I have tried to add this property in different places and with different formatings. But there is an error. So how do I set this property correctly?

Comment: @steavy - Why didn't you say what you tried in your question (useful information, you know)? And what error are you getting? Exactly?

Comment: nevermind. Resolved. Your answer helped. Thanks) I knew that I need to put this property there but didn`t know about correct formating.

Comment: @steavy - Yeah, the format is a bit too wrapped. It belongs in the XML encoded portion after "provider connection string=" within the XML encoded quotes...